# CSS vertical positioning, no height known

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I've got the following menu structure:

```
<div class="header" style="height: 150px;">
    <nav id="main-nav">
        <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li>menu item 1</li>
                <li>menu item 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Container `#main-nav` in this case has real `height: 20px;` (so `.menu-main-menu-container` has it, too). But when I try to vertically position entire menu in `.header` using this:

```
#main-nav {
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

The `#main-nav` instantly gets height of the `.header`! So, it's `height: 150px;` (according to Firebug) and I can't vertically position it.

How do I vertically position that? That's the bug I stumble upon quite often. When I add top: 0; and bottom: 0; it gets height of parent container. I don't know height of that menu.

Comment: When you add top:0, bottom:0 you are forcing it to the be the height of the container

Comment: Sam is right. It's not a bug, that's exactly how it should work. Giving an absolutely positioned element `top:0; bottom:0;` is a method of giving that element the height of the parent. What I don't understand is **where** you want to position it within the header.

Comment: Where exactly inside the header? Centered vertically? At the bottom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Situation when height of the parent is unknown and the height of the child known:
Set `top: 50%` and `margin-top: -10px` (`10px` = half the height of the nav).
Demo http://dabblet.com/gist/2819055

Situation when both the heights of the parent and the child are unknown:
Use a pseudo-element of `height: 100%`; `display: inline` & `vertical-align: middle` on both the pseudo-element and the child (nav in this case) - demo http://dabblet.com/gist/2819071

Answer (score -1):

I'm thinking that you mean center horizontally. In which case you cannot do that if your height is unknown by CSS only. You can use jQuery for that though. Take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/W5N6q/) fiddle.

It calculates the height of your menu and then calculates where it has to be positioned.